# JPA concurrency issue "On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, concurrency

I have a a concurrency issue I tried to solve with a while loop that attempts to save an entity multiple times until it hits some max retry count. I'd like to avoid talking about whether or not there are other ways to solve this problem. I have other Stackoverflow posts about that. :) Long story short: there's a unique constraint on a column that is derived and includes a numeric portion that keeps incrementing to avoid collisions. In a loop, I:

1. select max(some_value)
2. increment the result
3. attempt to save new object with this new result
4. explicitly flush the entity and, if that fails because of the unique index, I catch a DataAccessException.

All of this seems to work except when the loop goes back to step 1 and tries to select, I get:

```
17:20:46,111 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-3) HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
17:20:46,111 INFO  [my.Class] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-3) MESSAGE="Failed to save to database. Will retry (retry count now at: 9) Exception: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [SCHEMA_NAME.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement"
```

And a new Exception is caught. It seems like the first flush that causes the unique constraint violation and throws the `DataAccessException` doesn't clear the entity manager's batch. What's the appropriate way to deal with this? I'm using Spring with JPA and don't have direct access to the entity manager. I guess I could inject it if I need it but that's a painful solution to this problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot do that - once you flush something and it fails and an exception is thrown, the transaction will be marked as roll back. That means it doesnt matter that you catch the exception and proceed, you'll end up with a rollback.
Actually it doesnt matter at all what exception was thrown - by default Spring's transaction manager will rollback on every *unchecked* exception.
You can overcome it by specifically defining a `noRollbackFor` on the `@Transactional` annotation (providing you are using annotation driver transactions)

Edit - it also won't help you in case of this constraint violation, since the transaction will be probably marked as rollback at the database level.

Comment: Which databases mark transactions as rollback when you get a constraint violation?  (Honest question, I've never heard of this).

Comment: @WW. It happened to me in postgres. Im not sure about other databases. BTW it's not just constraint violation but actually ANY statement that failed - causes the entire transaction to be rollbacked

Answer (score 5):

I found this question getting same error. In my case the problem was caused by weird combination of trigger and row lock (see [PSQLException and lock issue when trigger added on table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57681970/653539)). However it took some time to discover this error is just consequence of primary error, not the cause. When Hibernate flushes session and some constraint violation happens, it receives some JDBC exception and in the finally block it tries to call `abortBatch`. When any statement remains in session, Hibernate emits this warning, though the actual error should be search for somewhere before.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I got the same exception and I could not figure out why my batch inserts were failing. PostgreSQL was complaining about a foreign key violated when the data was there.

I am using MapStruct to copy one Entity from one datasource to another Entity for a separate datasource, and I forgot to create getters/setters for a one-to-one relationship. I added the getter/setter, but forgot to rebuild my project to regenerate my mappers and the entity with the related table record was not getting inserted prior to inserting the record with the foreign key.

So, if you're using MapStruct, try rebuilding and make sure the Mapper is setting your entity, and that it's actually present before inserting.