# Use Spring and EJB transaction together

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, transactions, ejb-3.0

I am getting the error while try to add the entity into the DB. I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39734796/jpa-concurrency-issue-on-release-of-batch-it-still-contained-jdbc-statements). But it did not have much info regarding my issue

I have one EJB jar which I use to manage the get,save and update the entity.

Here is my remote ejb

```
@Remote
public abstract interface DatalayerService{
   public abstract void add(Object object)
}
```

Here is the implemetation

```
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class DatalayerServiceImpl implements DatalayerService{
  @PersistenceContext(name="myPersistenceUnit")
   EntityManager em = null;

  @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void add(Object object) throws FatalException{
        try {
            em.persist(object);
        }
        catch (Throwable e){
            throw manageDatalayerError(e);
        }
        finally {

        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to use the above ejb in my application

1)

```
@ComponentScan({"com.springboot"})
@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringEjbApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{


    public static void main(String args[]){
        SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.class,args);
    }



    @Bean
    public DatalayerService datalayerService() throws NamingException{
        return new DatalayerServiceImpl();
    }


    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws NamingException{
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.springboot.pojo"});
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("myPersistenceUnit");
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return em;
    }



    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException{
        return (DataSource) new JndiTemplate().lookup("openejb:Resource/MyDataSource");
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }


    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }


    private Properties additionalProperties(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", "3");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size", "2");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", "100");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "false");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

2)Rest Service

```
@RestController
public class HomeEndPoint{

    @Autowired
    private IUserService iUserService;

    @GetMapping("/createUser")
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = {ServiceExpectedException.class,FatalException.class,MandatoryParameterMissingFatalException.class})
    public void createUser() throws FatalException,ServiceExpectedException{
        iUserService.createUser();
    }

}
```

3)User Service and its impl

```
public interface IUserService{
   public void createUser() throws FatalException;
}

    @Service
@Transactional(rollbackFor = {ServiceExpectedException.class,FatalException.class,MandatoryParameterMissingFatalException.class})
public class UserServiceImpl implements IUserService{
     @Autowired
    private DatalayerGenericService datalayerGenericService;

     @Override
    public void createUser() throws FatalException,ServiceExpectedException{
     Team team = new Team(simpleContextService);
        team.setGroupName("MyTeam");
        team.setStoreId(100);
        // Team
        datalayerGenericService.add(team);
        Log.info(this,"add team ");
        // Build user1
        datalayerGenericService.add(user1);
        Log.info(this,"############################# Added User1 ######################################");
        // Build user2
        datalayerGenericService.add(user2);
        Log.info(this,"############################# Added User2 ######################################");

}
}
```

I tried to run the rest service with url

```
http://localhost:6180/SpringBootDatalayer/createUser
```

I am getting the below exception.

> INFO: (com.edifixio.springboot.service.impl.UserServiceImpl)
>
> ####################### teamOid 20 INFO: (com.edifixio.springboot.service.impl.UserServiceImpl)
>   
>   ####################### Added User1 ##################################### INFO: (com.edifixio.springboot.service.impl.UserServiceImpl)
>   
>   ####################### Added User2 ##################################### INFO : http-nio-6180-exec-1 : AbstractBatchImpl.release :    HHH000010: On release of batch it still
>
> contained JDBC statements 2018-03-27 16:28:17,683 : ERROR :
>   http-nio-6180-exec-1 : BatchingBatch.performExecution :    HHH000315:
>   Exception executing batch [java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry
>   0 insert into TEAM (CREATE_TIMESTAMP, PROJECT_GROUP_NAME,
>   LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP, STORE_ID, ID) values ('2018-3-27
>   16:28:17.447000 +5:30:0', 'MMA_TEST', '2018-3-27 16:28:17.503000
>   +5:30:0', 100, 21) was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.], SQL: insert into TEAM (CREATE_TIMESTAMP, PROJECT_GROUP_NAME,
>   LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP, STORE_ID, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

As you can see from the exception It was creating team,user1 and user2 with the use of datalayerGenericService. But tries to executes again to give AbstractBatchImpl.release :    HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements.

Here is the exception I got:

> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 1 insert into TEAM
>   (CREATE_TIMESTAMP, PROJECT_GROUP_NAME, LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP,
>   STORE_ID, ID) values ('2018-3-29 12:9:26.611000 +5:30:0', 'MMA_TEST',
>   '2018-3-29 12:9:26.836000 +5:30:0', 100, 23) was aborted.  Call
>   getNextException to see the cause.

How do I resolve this issue? Why the query executing twice?

If there is any exception occurs in EJB methods, it should rollback the transaction. But it is not happening

Note : If I remove @Transactional annotation from the service it works fine. 
I am using TomEE 7.0.2 server.

Comment: You have specified the transaction as `NOT_SUPPORTED` so no transaction will be started. Use `REQUIRED` instead. Also there is no EJB stuff involved here, regardless the fact that you added those annotations. Spring doesn't start an EJB container nor is one hence it will be just a regular spring bean.

Comment: There is a annotation  @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED) in the method. So EJB  stuffs are involved here.

Comment: No there isn't... You are only using an default transaction annotation that doesn't make it an EJB. Adding all those interfaces and annotations doesn't give you anything but added complexity and overhead in code that is silently ignored by Spring (apart from the `Transactional` as spring does support that).

Comment: So, if I understand your comment well, you were saying DatalayerServiceImpl is not an EJB?

Comment: Correct, it is simply a Spring Bean. Spring isn't an EJB container...

Comment: Yes. You were spot on. In my case the rollback did not happen, as it was throwing other than ServiceExpectedException.class,FatalException.class,MandatoryParameterMissingFatalException.class. It was working now because I am using rollbackFor = {Throwable.class}. Thanks for enlighten me

Comment: So I guess now your problem got solved. Am i right?

Comment: Yes. It was solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did I resolve this issue?

I was misunderstood that there is EJB stuff involved here
But @M. Deinum  clarified me that here no EJB involved, regardless the fact that I have added those annotations, which means my DatalayerServiceImpl is just a SpringBean.
Adding all those interfaces and annotations doesn't give me anything but added complexity and overhead in code that is silently ignored by Spring (apart from the Transactional as spring does support that).

Coming to my problem I have declared Team In Users class

```
@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST},fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="TEAM_ID",nullable=false)
@JsonBackReference
private Team team;
```

While creating the User I was referencing the Created team instance to Users class

I was doing

```
Team team = new Team(simpleContextService);
team.setGroupName("MMA_TEST");
team.setStoreId(100);
// Team
Long teamOid = datalayerGenericService.updateWithId(team);

Users user1 = new Users(simpleContextService);
...Set other fields
user1.setTeam(team);
```

As the Team declared as [Cascade type](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbqm/index.html) Persist inside Users, it was trying to insert the team when persisting the Users.

So I have changed the [Cascade type](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbqm/index.html) to MERGE. So it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you don't insert neither Users nor team. You persist them to PersistenceContext. When your code leaves

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = {ServiceExpectedException.class,FatalException.class,MandatoryParameterMissingFatalException.class})
    public void createUser()
```

It has to be commited or flushed or session closed as far as you have marked it as required. It failures on very first insertion (team) because of you didn't have some of any listed above.

And yes - you are using noting from EJB here. In fact you use Hibernate and only @Transactional as Spring service annotation has effect here.